# How to separate the negative and positive values from 3rd column in vim file?

Tags: vimscript, linux-ubuntu

I am dealing with a long data in the vim file. I want to separate the positive values and negative values in the 3rd column in separate files.

Example:

```
1.000 3.889  4.666

4.889 2.809 -8.687

3.896 4.797  2.808

2.797 4.098 -0.458
```

Now I want to have two separate files based on the positive and negative values in 3rd column.

I use an awk command as

```
awk '$3 ~ /\-/ { print $0 }' chh.dat1
```

but it is not working.

Comment: It's not clear if you want to do this at the command line in awk or if you want to do it within vim.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I’m not clear on what your desired output looks like, nor what « it’s not working » means. Please [edit]. (I’ve cleaned up some formatting, but I left in some linebreaks whose origin I wasn’t sure of. If they were markdown artifacts, please remove them; if they were part of the example text, leave them in.)

Answer (score 1):

Using vim I would do it with 2 steps

### put all lines with negatives on third column down

```
:g/^\(.*\s\+\)\{2}-\d/m$
```

Find all lines that has third column (space delimited) starting with `-` and some digit. Move that line at the end of buffer.

### write them to a separate file

```
vip:w ~/newfile.dat
```

Select a paragraph and write selection to the `~/newfile.dat`.

### remove all negatives from current file

```
gvd
```

Reselect and delete selection.

PS, although `sed` or `awk` might be a better choice for the task.